# Sort a list by digits appearing after trash digits in VIM

Tags: regex, sorting, vim

I need to sort and diff a few lists that have 1,000s of entries on them. The lists looks like:

```
11-2-3049_2007_squib.pdf
11-11-5476_2004_squib.pdf
13-2-5477_2006_squib.pdf
14-3-3045A_2004_squib.pdf
14-CMF-3046_2004_squib.pdf
14-2-3047_2005_squib.pdf
14-4-3048_2004_squib.pdf
15-7-3050P_2004_squib.pdf
```

I'm looking to sort by the number between the second `-` and before the `_`, such as `3049` in the first example.

I've not been able to combine the sort by column and regex stuff with any success. What do you all suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
:sort r  /\v^(.{-}-){2}\zs.{-}\ze_/
```

See

```
:help sort
```

for background here

The regex contains a few twists and turns:

- `\v` to engage *very magic* mode (reducing the need for escaping)
- `\zs` and `\ze` to mark the begin and end of the actual match result
- `{-}` to perform non-greedy kleene-star match (in Perl notation, `.{-}` would be `.*?`)

Comment: @kev I keep forgetting that. I tend to include it because often it is not (e.g. `:subst` defaults to current line). Habits :(

Comment: I did not know that you nest quantifiers like that! Nor that `\zs` `\ze` were what the sort algorithm was looking for. My 13,050 files thank you!

Comment: if the number has a variable number of digits you will need a leading n to avoid things like 100 coming before 2 :sort rn  /\v^(.{-}-){2}\zs.{-}\ze_/

Answer (score 4):

Use the external `sort` program:

```
:%!sort -n -t- -k3,3
```